# add prefix inside textfield in swift(iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to create a textfield with prefix "R_" which can not be editable.
here is my code...

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (pay_amount.text?.count)! == 2 {
        pay_amount.text = "R_"
        return false
    }else{

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inspect the range:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return range.lowerBound > 1 
}
```

Comment: @DeepnarainRai Glad I could help